# WebSphere AS default page

Tags: websphere-liberty, application-server

I'm using embedded WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5.5 in our application. It has default welcome page which looks like this:

[image: welcome page]
Is there a way how to change it to my custom content?

I was looking for source files in WAS directory, searching by source code, image resource name (liberty-was-202.png) etc. with no success. I guess the page is somehow generated.

Note I'm on embedded WebSphere where I didn't find a way how to access the administration console (maybe there's some?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server's configuration file (like server.xml) you can specify
`<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage="false" />`
to disable the welcome page, then just bind your application to the '/' context root.
There's documentation here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_config_httpDispatcher.html

Comment: I see "enableWelcomePage" is not even needed when I bind an application to context root in server.xml. It's pretty straightforward. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend @M.Broz's answer, If you can't set a root application for some reason, it's also possible to inject a JavaScript into the server configuration so that user is redirected to the website you want.
Here's the solution for **redirection**:

`<httpDispatcher enableWelcomePage="false" appOrContextRootMissingMessage='&lt;script&gt;document.location.href="/myapp/home/";&lt;/script&gt;'></httpDispatcher>`